# Choosing an OLED / LCD Dispaly

Tags: display, serial, i2c

I'm building a simple device where my Raspberry Pi talks to Google Calendar, and displays information about where I'm at on my office door.  My code is all in Python

It was simple until I started trying to choose a display: Serial, Parallel, I2C, SPI, and then even when you find one you think might work, you find loads of forums about troubles with the raspberry pi pull-ups, etc. It's all quite overwhelming!

Displays seem to have up to 20(ish) pins, although most tutorials I see use a maximum of 7 wires. How do you go about selecting a display that will work well with the Raspberry Pi?  What are red flags?

Right now the easiest solution seems to be sending serial commands to an Arduino, which can then talk to the display... but this seems silly.

Comment: What physical size?  How many pixels?  Colour or monochrome? How much power?  What update rate?

Comment: All Good Questions! I wanted this question to be more general than my specific case, but in particular how much power can the Raspberry Pi give/handle? What update rate can the raspberry pi handle?

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished setting up an Adafruit OLED without any issues. They use SPI which means you don't have to use a lot of pins. Here is the tutorial I followed:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-oled-displays-for-raspberry-pi/setting-up

I guess it's worth researching if there is a library that has been ported to Rpi - then if there is sufficient documentation to support it / examples online.

The only issues with py-gaugette is that there isn't great deal of documentation. But this should suffice in your python project.